# Firebase debug view iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, firebase

I am trying to catch events in the debug view in firebase.
I catch only events of type [screen_view and user_engagement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68aS7.png)
I enabled in arguments passed on launch the -FIRDebugEnabled and made sure the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE=disabled is removed from environment.
I configure the firebaseAnalytics and enabling collection as other posts suggested.
Even though I can see i'm reaching in code the logEvent method I can't see other events other than the two I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
I had in the logs "Attempted to register protocol FIRAnalyticsInterop, but it already has an implementation."
Which led me to the discussion here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9472

TL;DR:
The problem I had two Target which included the firanalytics pod.
Had to remove from one of them.